# Ciclo en donde el nombre de una variable va incrementando

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código en PHP donde declaro mis variables dentro de un arreglo, lo que busco es hacer un ciclo donde pueda generar la configuración dependiendo del número de "apples" seleccionadas, donde no he podido avanzar es en hacer que la variable vaya incrementando su número, es decir que vaya en función de $i
PHP:

```
$_['appleNum'] = 5;
$_['appleBrand1'] = "a";
$_['appleState1'] = "aa";
$_['appleBrand2'] = "b";
$_['appleState2'] = "bb";
$_['appleBrand3'] = "c";
$_['appleState3'] = "cc";
$_['appleBrand4'] = "d";
$_['appleState4'] = "dd";
$_['appleBrand5'] = "e";
$_['appleState5'] = "ee";

for ($i = 1; $i <= $_['appleNum']; $i++) {
    $_['appleConfig'] = "edit APPLE" . $i . "
 set brand " . $_['appleBrand#'] . "
 set state " . $_['appleState#'] .;
}
```

Comment: Pon bien el código. No dejes bucles sin cerrar, nos despista y no sabemos que puede venir después. Recuerda que debes poner un [example] pero que sea completo, no solo un cacho que da errores de sintaxis básicos.

Comment: Intuyo que esto es más simple de como intentas resolverlo, pero falta contexto en la pregunta y eso no ayuda a comprender el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mi gusto usas una sintaxis un poco rara para nombrar variables. Y no has puesto bien como se cierra ese **for** en tu pregunta.

Aún así, creo que lo que buscas es esto:

```php
$_['appleNum'] = 5;
$_['appleBrand1'] = "a";
$_['appleState1'] = "aa";
$_['appleBrand2'] = "b";
$_['appleState2'] = "bb";
$_['appleBrand3'] = "c";
$_['appleState3'] = "cc";
$_['appleBrand4'] = "d";
$_['appleState4'] = "dd";
$_['appleBrand5'] = "e";
$_['appleState5'] = "ee";

for ($i = 1; $i <= $_['appleNum']; $i++) {
    $_['appleConfig'][] = "edit APPLE" . $i . "
    set brand " . $_['appleBrand'.$i] . "
    set state " . $_['appleState'.$i];
}
print_r(implode(" ",$_['appleConfig']));
```

Lo cual acaba devolviendo esto:

```
edit APPLE1
    set brand a
    set state aa edit APPLE2
    set brand b
    set state bb edit APPLE3
    set brand c
    set state cc edit APPLE4
    set brand d
    set state dd edit APPLE5
    set brand e
    set state ee
```

Seguramente lo quieres al principio de linea y partirlas de otra forma, pero eso no era lo que preguntabas y entiendo que ya puedes areglarlo tu directamente ahora que ya has conseguido una salida aproximada a lo que esperabas conseguir creo.